# Заменить тип кавічек в строковой переменной с одинарных на двойные

Tags: php, строки, типы-данных, замена, кавычки

Дана задача ниже.
Надо вывести строку $str и массив $arr из этой строки (в массиве должны быть только цифры).
Вопрос: как изменить тип кавычек на двойные вместо одинарных, кроме как руцями?
Просто сделать замену $i $r через str_replace - сказали плохая практика.
ЗЫ: свой путь только начинаю, в полном объеме знаниями и навыками не обладаю.

Дано:

```
$k = 8;
$r = 1;
$str = '21,36,0,$i,3,19,125,$r,42,';
```

Решение:

```
//заменяем переменные на значения
$str = str_replace('$k', $k, $str);
$str = str_replace('$r', $r, $str);

// обрезаем лишние запятые
$str2 = trim($str, ',');

// переводим в массив
$arr = explode(',', $str2);

// Для каждой пары ключ-значение в массиве arr проверяем, что значение является цифрой. Если нет, то удаляем.
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($value) == false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
// пересобираем массив без пустых значений
$arr = array_values($arr);

// Выводим в браузер $str
print_r ($str);

// Выводим с новой строки несортированный массив
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Кавычки, после инициализации переменной никак вроде (может поправят).. А кто и почему вам сказал, что str_replace - плохая практика ?

Comment: мне сказали такое на собеседовании. Было употреблено с эпитетом ОЧЕНЬ.

Comment: Ну, надеюсь вы не трудоустроились в эту ОЧЕНЬ хорошую компанию. Это ни разу не плохая практика т.к. работает раза в два быстрее той же регулярки.